# Add a record in many tables based on ID of First table

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model, controller

Guys I've 3 tables as follows:

- Project {id, name, owner, ....}
- ProjectMilestones {id, project_id, name ....}
- UserProjects {id, project_id, ....}

Here, Once I create a New Project, I'll fetch the **Project_ID** *(@@IDENTITY)* column, and Create a new row in both **ProjectMilestones** and **UserProjects** tables with this ID. My code looks as follows

```
def create
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    # Instantiate a new object using form parameters
      @project = Project.new(params[:project])
      if @project.save
        # if project saves, Create a new insteance into User Projects
        @userproject=UserProject.new(
        :project_id=>@project.id
        )
        @userproject.save

        # Create a new insteance into ProjectMilestone
        @projectmilestone=ProjectMilestone.new(
        :project_id=>@project.id,
        :milestone_id=>12,
        :milestone_date=>@project.created_at
        )
        @projectmilestone.save
        flash[:notice] = "A new project has been created successfully"
        redirect_to(:action => 'list')
      else
      # If save fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
        render('new')
      end
    end
  end
```

It's working fine for me. I want to know is there any optimized approach available for this? so I can move Business logic to Model and Let Project create all associated records or fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always want to create a new UserProject and a new ProjectMilestone after creating a new Project, you can use one of the ActiveRecord-Callbacks.

In your Project-Model you can add this callback:

```
after_create :create_other_models
```

You can now copy the part for creating the other models in the method create_other_models.